# Filter to list after check of nullable

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to scroll through a list within another list to retrieve its size, but I need to add the filter to that list, but I can't imagine how I could do that. Someone help?

```java
listaInscricaoTipoTrab.stream().mapToInt(itt -> Optional.ofNullable(itt.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores()).map(List::size).orElse(0)).sum()
```

Inside the `getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores()` I have an ENUM `getAutorCoautor()` where I want it to count only when the `getAutorCoautor().equals(AutorCoautor.AUTOR)`.
In the end, I want you to return the number of objects in the listInscricaoTipoTrab with the same type of AutorCoautor was found, if you don't find anything, it will return 0.

I tried this but without success:

```java
listaInscricaoTipoTrab.stream().mapToInt(itt -> Optional.ofNullable(itt.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores().stream().filter(tta -> tta.getAutorCoautor().equals(AutorCoautor.AUTOR)).collect(Collectors.toList())).map(List::size).orElse(0)).sum()
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at br.pucpr.pergamum.eventos.view.vm.SubmeterTrabalhoViewModel.lambda$12(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:566)
```

Comment: Why can't you add a filter? Please explain in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, I described it better. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if it works or not.

```
listaInscricaoTipoTrab
    .stream()
    .mapToInt(itt -> 
            itt.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores()
                .stream()
                .filter(tta -> tta.getAutorCoautor().equals(AutorCoautor.AUTOR))
                .mapToInt(List::size)
                .sum()
    .sum();
```

Comment: The code didn't work, apparently there's a problem.

Comment: Okay, can you share your java classes, that are involved here?

Comment: @RomeuFernandesBessa I have some questions. What is the data type of `listaInscricaoTipoTrab`, what does `itt.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores()` return?

Comment: the type of listaInscricaoTipoTrab is InscricaoTipoTrab and itt.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores() returns an object  InscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutor which contains the enum that will be used to filter AutorCoautor

Comment: Is `listaInscricaoTipoTrab` an instance of array or list? `itt.getInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAutores()` it returns an `object`, not list or array, right?

Comment: Both are lists, but the listInscricaoTipoTrabalho is parent of the listInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAuthors, so I need to give a stream in the parent list and a flatMap in the child list, to be able to filter by the enum Author that is inside the object of the listInscricaoTipoTrabalhoAuthors, and then I want to return the total value found in both parent lists, and both child lists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239342/discussion-between-mazedul-islam-and-romeu-fernandes-bessa).